# Get the "watch" command output in java getRuntime().exec

Tags: java, linux, bash

I am trying to get the output from `watch free -b` and/or `top` commands in java but when i call it using the getRuntime().exec() method in java, i get an error. Here is what i have tried:

### Attempt #1

```
// This java code
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/bash", "-c", "watch -t -n 1 free -b");
pb.redirectOutput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT);
pb.redirectInput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT);
pb.redirectError(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT);
Process process = pb.start();
int exitVal = process.waitFor();

// Gives this error
Error opening terminal: unknown
```

### Attempt #2

```
// This java code
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/bin/bash");
OutputStream stdin = process.getOutputStream();
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(stdin);
pw.println("watch -t -n 1 free -b < /dev/tty > /dev/tty");
pw.close();
int exitVal = process.waitFor();

// Gives this error
Error opening terminal: unknown
```

### Attempt #3

```
// This java code
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/bin/bash");
OutputStream stdin = process.getOutputStream();
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(stdin);
pw.println("watch -t -n 1 free -b < /dev/tty > /dev/tty");
pw.close();
int exitVal = process.waitFor();

// Gives this error
/bin/bash: line 1: /dev/tty: No such device or address
```

Also, if i try to pass the command this way to the process builder

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/usr/bin/watch -t -n 1 /usr/bin/free -b");
```

I get this error:

```
Cannot run program "/usr/bin/watch -t -n 1 /usr/bin/free -b": error=2, No such file or directory
```

Instead, when i pass the command `top` instead of `watch` i get the following error:

```
TERM environment variable not set
```

I think the problems are related because they both work with interactive shell, and also because any other command ( like ping for example ) works perfectly fine. But i am not sure at all. 
Is there a way to continuously get the output from a command like watch in java?

Comment: You might have better luck using a command like this one `sh -c "while [ 1 ]; do free -b ; sleep 1 ; done"` that doesn't need a tty.

Comment: I wanted to avoid it as i wanted to find a solution ( if exists ) for both the command watch and a command like top. Those commands update the shell regularly already so there is no need to loop a command over and over. If i were to take your solution, how do i do it using the command "top"?

Comment: For top, there's a switch `-b` (batch mode) that makes it output just a stream of date instead of trying to manage a terminal.

Comment: I you really want to use `watch`, you can try this: `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/usr/bin/watch", "-t", "-n", "1", "sh", "-c", "\"free -b </dev/tty >/dev/tty\"");`

Comment: One more comment -- maybe a little off-topic, but -- it you're implementing a system monitor app, you could consider simply reading `/proc/meminfo` periodically in java instead of running "free" to get the memory stats. It would be more efficient.

Comment: Your solution for the watch command still gives me this error:  `Error opening terminal: unknown`. I will consider looking into `/proc/meminfo` so thanks for the tip. Though, I still want to find a solution for getting the output of a command that handles the shell like watch.